# ReportViewer is extremely slow after migrating to VS2012

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

Recently we migrated our VS2008 windows application to VS2012. Everything seems to work fine except the report viewer. I am not saying it's not working at all, it works but if I am calling the report for the very first time, it takes extremely long to display i.e around 20 to 30 seconds. But after that each time I load the report it works fine and takes about 2-3 seconds.

I googled about it and found some answers, they say Visual studio looks for the DLLs on the network and probably it's true because if I disconnect my LAN cable it works fine. It means VS is looking for the DLLs first on the network and then my local computer. Is this true? If yes then how can I force it to look for the DLLs on my local computer? Or I am completely wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I only know that after the report runs for the first time after deployment, an .rdl.data file is created.

Subsequent report runs must reference the data file first, therefore causing the Report to run quicker. Since this file is built only once, I prefer to run each report in production to allow the creation the .RDL.DATA file.

It's an extra step in the deployment process but the Report User will never experience the wait time.